# Remove mapView from parent, then add back later

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I am trying to remove my map view from the parent view, then add it back at some point:

```
- (IBAction)setMapType:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0: {
            if ([self.mapView isDescendantOfView:self.view] == false) {
                [self.view insertSubview:self.mapView atIndex:0];
            }

            break;
        }

        case 1:
            [self.mapView removeFromSuperview];
            break;
    }
}
```

When I click the second button in my segmented control the mapview does get removed.  However when I click the first button it does not seem to get added back correctly.  What I mean by that is that it does get added back to the parent view but the map does not appear.  I have tried adding it the top of the subviews and the bottom with the same result.

You may ask why I would want to do that (as I am asking myself).  I am trying to give my users the ability to point at different map types (other than iOS).  MKMapView will point to iOS maps which is awesome but I want to throw in RMMapView (mapbox/routeme) map view as well.  I am not sure what is the best course of action to swap in and out map views like this.  Should I delete old map views on swap and create news ones?  Or should I keep around the old maps view but just remove them from view?

Answer (score 1):

> What I mean by that is that it does get added back to the parent view but the map does not appear.

That is indeed strange and shouldn't be happening.

As for approach, I would recommend keeping a strong reference to both map views upon first use of each, then remove the unused one each time, release/`nil` it, and free up the memory. Then, next time it's needed, recreate it with the same style, center, and zoom level. In the case of MapKit, it may be easier to think in terms of `region` instead of zoom, however,

Comment: I think what was happening is that I added the MapView as a property via the storyboard.  The property was set as weak.  Guessing that maybe when I removed it from its parent view it was released (not 100% sure though).  Making the MapView a private variable 'fixed' it.

Comment: Possible I did find a bug.  If I remove the RMMapView from the superview and then added back in the following error is thrown: Mapbox[29859:a0b] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x263dff00 V:[UIButton:0xcaba5f0]-(-472)-[_UILayoutGuide:0xc891680]>

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be adding the subView  beneath other existing subViews? The lower the index, the lower the z-order. Try using addSubView: instead, which inserts the subView above every other subView:

```
[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
```

or:

```
[self.view insertSubview:self.mapView atIndex:[self.view.subviews count]];
```

or simply send it to front after adding:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.mapView];
```

I would personally keep the mapViews around and add/remove them to the super view as needed. Yet another possible approach would be to keep them in the super view and toggle their **hidden** property whenever the selected segment index changes.

Comment: Would you be concerned about memory usage with keeping around both map views?  I.E. my users can add markers to the map. I could potentially have a lot of markers around in a mapview that is not shown.

Comment: To me, it is really a trade-off between performance and memory usage. Coming from the point of view of ensuring a reasonable user experience, you may not want to reload all markers every time you switch the segment (which could lead to a noticeable lag especially on lower-end devices). If you are uncertain, you can try to do a memory profiling with XCode to ascertain if the memory consumption stays within acceptable limits.